# Secured way to allow PHP script write permissions to a folder

Tags: 16.04, server, php

I have a website at `/var/www/html`, and i have a PHP script which uploads user selected image to `/var/www/html/images`. The script will not work unless I change permissions on on `/images` folder to write.

What would be the best option to allow the script to have write permissions on this folder? Or, it's something better done via PHP code, so that the PHP code opens the folder to writing everytime it's executed?

Or, maybe put the images folder outside /var/www and give it 777 permission there? (Or that's also not good)

Answer (score 2):

The web-server must have write permission for the directory where the 
image is to be stored. There are 3 options:

1. Let the web-server be the owner of the directory and set 
   owner permissions on the directory to u=rw (644)
2. Let the web-server's group be the group of the directory and set
   the group permissions on the directory to g=rw (664)
3. Set the permissions for others on the directory for o=rw (666)

The first option is usually the best way to  secure the directory.

But if you have no root access to the server it could be difficult to
delete, move or rename files when accessed by FTP. If this is a serious
problem, option 2 is justifiable.

There is usually no need to use option 3.